# Java Spring Security - problem with authorize

Tags: java, http, spring-security

i have problem with **Authorize in Spring Security**.
i'm writing a simple organizer app and there is a 14 roles, but i'm making whole tests on **ROLE_ADMIN**, and it didn't works. typing /admin get's me to /denied page :(
Can you find a problem here ?

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSec) throws Exception {
        httpSec.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_PRODUCTION_MANAGER", "ROLE_FOREMAN").antMatchers("/workingpanel")
                // Another .antMatchers //
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");
    }
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Are you logging in via form before trying to go to the /admin endpoint? Is there an actual controller behind that endpoint? What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", ...) to   .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN",....) as Spring Security adds ROLE prefix to each role automatically. For example

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
.antMatchers("/admin/** ").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER",...)
...
```

}

Comment: Its seems to be so easy...but if you dont know that... :D  thanks dude :-) works fine